# How do I get the if statement correct in the lines that has it in the program?

Tags: php, html, xampp

We are encountering problems with the `if` statements in the program and cannot run it in the local host in the `xampp.`your text

`your text`

```
<title>Calculate your solar array size</title>
<style>

    form{
        width:500px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #9E9E9E;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        color: white;
    }
    select {
        font-size:20px;         
        padding:5px;
        background: #607D8B ;
        text-align: center;

    }


</style>
```

```
[tag:`type here`]
```

## Cost Calculator

### Enter Your Average kWh per month and % of Electricity bill to offset

```
<h3>Enter the kWh used per month:</h3>
    
        80
        90
        100
        110
        120
        130
        140
        150
        160
        170
        180
        190
        200
        210
        220
        230
        240
        250
        260
        270
        280
        290
        300
        310
        320
        330
        340
        350
        360
        370
        380
        390
        400
        410
        420
        430
        440
        450
        460
        470
        480
        490
        500
        510
        520
        530
        540
        550
        560
        570
        580
        590
        600
        610
        620
        630
        640
        650
        660
        670
        680
        690
        700
        710
        720
        730
        740
        750
        760
        770
        780
        790
        800
        810
        820
        830
        840
        850
        860
        870
        880
        890
        900
        910
        920
        930
        940
        950
        960
        970
        980
        990
        1000
        1100
        1200
        1300
        1400
        1500
        1600
        1700
        1800
        1900
        2000
        2100
        2200
        2300
        2400
        2500
        2600
        2700
        2800
        2900
        3000
        3100
        3200
        3300
        3400
        3500
        3600
        3700
        3800
        3900
        4000
        4100
        4200
        4300
        4400
        4500
        4600
        4700
        4800
        4900
        5000
        5100
        5200
        5300
        5400
        5500
        5600
        5700
        5800
        5900
        6000
        6100
        6200
        6300
        6400
        6500
        6600
        6700
        6800
        6900
        7000
        7100
        7200
        7300
        7400
        7500

    </select>
    <h4>Enter the % of Electricity Bill you want to cover:</h4>
    <select name="offset">
         <option value=5>5%</option>
         <option value=10>10%</option>
         <option value=15>15%</option>
         <option value=20>20%</option>
         <option value=25>25%</option>
         <option value=30>30%</option>
         <option value=35>35%</option>
         <option value=40>40%</option>
         <option value=45>45%</option>
         <option value=50>50%</option>
         <option value=55>55%</option>
         <option value=60>60%</option>
         <option value=65>65%</option>
         <option value=70>70%</option>
         <option value=75>75%</option>
         <option value=80>80%</option>
         <option value=85>85%</option>
         <option value=90>90%</option>
         <option value=95>95%</option>
         <option value=100>100%</option>
         <option value=105>105%</option>
         <option value=110>110%</option>
         <option value=115>115%</option>
         <option value=120>120%</option>
         <option value=125>125%</option>
         <option value=130>130%</option>
         <option value=135>135%</option>
         <option value=140>140%</option>
         <option value=145>145%</option>
         <option value=150>150%</option>
         <option value=155>155%</option>
         <option value=160>160%</option>
         <option value=165>165%</option>
         <option value=170>170%</option>
         <option value=175>175%</option>
         <option value=180>180%</option>
         <option value=185>185%</option>
         <option value=190>190%</option>
         <option value=195>195%</option>
         <option value=200>200%</option>
         <option value=205>205%</option>
         <option value=210>210%</option>
         <option value=215>215%</option>
         <option value=220>220%</option>
         <option value=225>225%</option>
         <option value=230>230%</option>
         <option value=235>235%</option>
         <option value=240>240%</option>
         <option value=245>245%</option>
         <option value=250>250%</option>
         <option value=255>255%</option>
         <option value=260>260%</option>
         <option value=265>265%</option>
         <option value=270>270%</option>
         <option value=275>275%</option>
         <option value=280>280%</option>
         <option value=285>285%</option>
         <option value=290>290%</option>
         <option value=295>295%</option>
         <option value=300>300%</option>
         <option value=305>305%</option>
         <option value=310>310%</option>
         <option value=315>315%</option>
         <option value=320>320%</option>
         <option value=325>325%</option>
         <option value=330>330%</option>
         <option value=335>335%</option>
         <option value=340>340%</option>
         <option value=350>350%</option>
         <option value=355>355%</option>
         <option value=360>360%</option>
         <option value=365>365%</option>
         <option value=370>370%</option>
         <option value=375>375%</option>
         <option value=380>380%</option>
         <option value=385>385%</option>
         <option value=390>390%</option>
         <option value=395>395%</option>
         <option value=400>400%</option>
         <option value=405>405%</option>
         <option value=410>410%</option>
         <option value=415>415%</option>
         <option value=420>420%</option>
         <option value=425>425%</option>
         <option value=430>430%</option>
         <option value=435>435%</option>
         <option value=440>440%</option>
         <option value=445>445%</option>
         <option value=450>450%</option>
         <option value=455>455%</option>
         <option value=460>460%</option>
         <option value=465>465%</option>
         <option value=470>470%</option>
         <option value=475>475%</option>
         <option value=480>480%</option>
         <option value=485>485%</option>
         <option value=490>490%</option>
         <option value=495>495%</option>
         <option value=500>500%</option>

    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click and Calculate:">
    </form>

     <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $kWh=$_POST['kWh'];

    $offsetpercent = 0.0;
    $offset = 0.0;
    $offsetpercent = $offset / 100;
    $offsetpercent = $offsetpercent + 1;
     
    $size=$kWh / 30 / 4.5 * 1.15 * 1.2 * $offsetpercent;
    
    echo '<br> This is the Solar Array Size in kW: </b>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $size = number_format($size);
    echo '<br />';




         $kWh=true;
     if  ($kWh < 300){
               echo  "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 1kW Solis Single Phase Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P16,200";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "2ND OPTION:.1kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P24,975.00";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "OFF GRID INVERTER: 1000W 12V/24V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P6,075 ";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "HYBRID INVERTER: 3.6kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P60,000";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "HYBRID OPTION 2: 3kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) SOFAR Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: 71,550";

           } elseif ($kWh >= 301 && $kWh < 481){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 2.7kW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P20,250,";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "2ND OPTION: 3kW (Single MPPT) G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter (Grid Tie) Unit Price: P32,400";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "3RD OPTION: 3.3KW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P22,275";
               echo '<br />';
               echo " 4TH OPTION: 1.6Kw G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P27,675 ";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "OFF GRID INVERTER: 2000W 12V/24V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P15,525 ";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "HYBRID INVERTER: 3.6kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P60,000 ";
               echo '<br />';
               echo "HYBRID OPTION 2: 3kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) SOFAR Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: 71,550";
           } elseif ($kWh >= 481 && $kWh < 661){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 2.7kW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P20,250 \n
               2ND OPTION: 2.2kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverterr (Grid Tie) Unit Price: 30,375 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 3000W 12V/24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P16,875 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 3.6kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P60,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 3kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) SOFAR Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: 71,550";
           } elseif($kWh >= 661 && $kWh < 751){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 2.7kW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P20,250 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 3000W 12V/24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P16,875 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 3.6kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P60,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 3kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) SOFAR Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: 71,550";
           } elseif($kWh >= 751 && $kWh < 901){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 3.3KW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie), Unit Price: P22,275 \n
               2ND OPTION: 3kW (Single MPPT) G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverterr (Grid Tie) Unit Price: 32,400 \n
               3RD OPTION: 3kW (Dual MPPT) G2 Unit Price: 35,100,   \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 3000W 12V/24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P16,875 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 3.6kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P60,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 3kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) SOFAR Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: 71,550";
           } elseif($kWh >= 901 && $kWh < 991){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 3.3KW G3 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie), Unit Price: P22,275 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 4000W 24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P29,700 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 5kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P70,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 4kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) Unit Price: 81,000";
           } elseif($kWh >= 991 && $kWh < 1201){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 5kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P36,450 \n
               OPTION 2: 5kW (Dual MPPT) Solis Single Phase Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P38,475 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 4000W 24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P29,700 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 5kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P70,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 4kW 48V (HYD3000-ES) Unit Price: 81,000";
           } elseif($kWh >= 1201 && $kWh < 1501){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 5kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P36,450 \n
               OPTION 2: 5kW (Dual MPPT) Solis Single Phase Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P38,475 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 5000W 24V/48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P39,150 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 5kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P70,000 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 6kW SOLIS HYBRID Inverter Unit Price: 74,250 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 3: 5kW 48V(HYD5000-ES) Unit Price: 86,400";
            } elseif($kWh >= 1501 && $kWh < 1801){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 6kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P37,800 \n
               OPTION 2: 6kW (Dual MPPT) Solis Single Phase Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P39,150 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 6000W 48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P41,850 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 6kW SOLIS HYBRID Inverter Unit Price: 74,250 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 2: 6kW 48V(HYD5000-ES) Unit Price: P99,900 \n
               HYBRID OPTION 3: 8kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P118,750";
           } elseif($kWh >= 1801 && $kWh < 2101){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 7.5kW G2 SOFAR 1Phase Inverter(Grid Tie) Unit Price: P40,500 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 8000W 48V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P74,250 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 8kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P118,750";
           } elseif($kWh >= 2101 && $kWh < 2401){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 8kW (Dual MPPT) Solis Single Phase Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P39,150 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 8000W 96V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P74,250 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 8kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P118,750";
           } elseif($kWh >= 2401 && $kWh < 3001){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: Single Phase 10kw DEYE Grid Tie Inverter Unit Price: P58,050 \n
               OPTION 2: 10kW 220V SOLIS 3-Phase Inverter 220V Delta Unit Price: P85,725 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 10kW 96V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P94,500 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 16kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P220,000";
           } elseif($kWh >= 3001 && $kWh < 3301){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 11kW (SOFAR 11KTL-X) SOFAR 3 Phase Inverter 380V WYE Unit Price: P86,400 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: CONTACT SOLAR COMPANY FOR CUSTOM INSTALLATION.\n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 16kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P220,000";
           } elseif ($kWh >= 3301 && $kWh < 4801){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 20kW (SOFAR 20000TL-G2) SOFAR 3 Phase Inverter 380V WYE Unit Price: P116,640 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 20kW 196V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P324,000 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: 16kW DEYE On Grid Hybrid Inverter Unit Price: P220,000";
           } elseif($kWh >= 4801 && $kWh < 6001){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 20kW (SOFAR 20000TL-G2) SOFAR 3 Phase Inverter 380V WYE Unit Price: P116,640 \n
               OPTION 2: 20kW 220V SOLIS 3-Phase Inverter 220V Delta Unit Price: 162,000 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: 20kW 196V SNAT SOLAR INVERTER Unit Price: P324,000 \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: CONTACT SOLAR COMPANY FOR CUSTOM INSTALLATION.";
           } elseif($kWh >= 6001 && $kWh < 7501){
               echo "MINIMUM POWER LOWEST PRICE INVERTER: 25kW 220V SOLIS 3-Phase Inverter 220V Delta Unit Price: 162,000 \n
               OFF GRID INVERTER: CONTACT SOLAR COMPANY FOR CUSTOM INSTALLATION. \n
               HYBRID INVERTER: CONTACT SOLAR COMPANY FOR CUSTOM INSTALLATION.";
           } else {
           echo "CONTACT SOLAR COMPANY FOR CUSTOM INSTALLATION.";

         }
           }
    ?>

    <br />
    <br />`your text`
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    
    <img src="new folder/Canadian_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/Trina_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/Inverter_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/jingko_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/JinkoMono_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/SunriMono_Solar.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
    <img src="new folder/Sunri_Solarr.jpg" alt="Solar Panel" >
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask] to learn how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You set the

```
$kWh = true;
```

var one line above the if to true. Then you check if the variable is lower than 300, you may remove the line highlighted above.

Comment: "I tried removing the line $kWh = true; already it still doesn't echo the results It only echoes the last else statement."

Comment: I've looked into your code again. The variable kWh is always not declared, because the HTML form doesn't submit it. You have to set a name in the form. Example: <input type="text" name="kWh">

Comment: i tried it also but not working again

Comment: I couldn't find any opening form tag. You may look into your code again and copy it into a HTML checker.